# Access page data on component

Tags: vue.js, layout, vuex, nuxt.js, apollo

I'm writing my first app using NUXT. I'm stuck at this issue for 2 days, so I decided to ask even if I think this is a question with a simple answer (it has to be).

On my project's *layouts* I have a default.vue and a home.vue

default.vue:

```
<template>  
  <div>
    <!-- call Header component, this has an nav menu -->
    <Header />

    <!-- call Hero component -->
    <Hero />

    <nuxt />

    <Footer />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '~/components/Header.vue'  
import Footer from '~/components/Footer.vue'
import Hero from '~/components/Hero.vue'  

export default {  
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer,
    Hero
  },
}
</script>
```

I want  to display data from each page (title, subtitle and imageUrl). This data sometimes come from an apollo query request other times are defined on page file.

I've read the docs and searched here for the answer but I wans't able to implement it. I think it has to be done thought *Vuex store* but I don't know how.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action) action in vuex as one way to populate page data.

If you are using nuxt >= 2.12, [you can use the new-and-improved fetch hook](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/#layout-components) inside your layouts to make your apollo queries.

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT!

So, it took a time to figure out, but I've learnt a lot during this process.
I'll let here some references I've used to come with this solution.

- [Very nice article on passing data through props, custom events and Vuex Store](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/data-components-vue-js/)
- [CodeSandBox from Nuxt Documentation.](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/vuex-store?from-embed=&file=/pages/website.vue:490-586)
- [This question has a method to await apollo data and then render data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57668110/vuejs-wait-on-apollo-before-rendering-data)

Let's go to the way I did it. I don't know if it's the best, but worked like a charm here.

I've created a *hero.js* file on my *store* folder:

```
  data: {
    title: "",
    subtitle: "",
    imgUrl: ""
  }
})

export const mutations = {
  setData (state, obj) {
    state.data = {...state.data, ...obj}
  }
}

export const getters = {
  getHero (state) {
    return state.data
  }
}
```

Then on my *default.vue* I did:

```
  <div>
    <!-- call Header component -->
    <Header />

    <!-- call Hero component with his slots-->
    <Hero>
      <template v-slot:title>
        <h1 class="title">{{ hero.title }}</h1>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:subtitle>
        <h2 class="subtitle">{{ hero.subtitle }}</h2>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:heroImg>
        <img :src="hero.imgUrl" />
      </template>
    </Hero>

    <!-- This is where all yours pages will be -->
    <nuxt />

    <Footer />

  </div>
</template>

<script>  
// Import Header component
import Header from '~/components/Header.vue'  
import Footer from '~/components/Footer.vue'  
import Hero from '~/components/Hero.vue'  

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      //declaring hero Obj to contain hero data
      hero: {
        title: "",
        subtitle: "",
        imgUrl: ""
      }
    }
  },

  components: {
    Header,
    Footer,
    Hero
  },

  //Getting getHero getter from hero.js and saving it to newHero
  computed: mapGetters({
    newHero: 'hero/getHero'
  }),

  //watching newHero to change and then updating this.hero Obj. This action will update the displayed data
  watch: {
    newHero: function (obj) {
      this.hero = {...this.hero, ...obj}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here I declare the variables and store than into Vuex Store:

```
<template>  
...
</template>

<script>  

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      hero: {
        title: "Awesome Static title",
        subtitle: "Awesome static subtitle"
      }
    }
  },

  //Saving the declared Hero to Vuex Store, then my default.vue will be able to get it through this.$store.getters  
  mounted() {
    this.$store.commit("hero/setData", this.hero);
  },
}
</script>
```

At some pages the title are fetched from the database (GraphQL using Apollo). Then I did:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
import getLojaInfo from '~/apollo/queries/loja/loja.gql'

export default {  
  //declaring data
  data() {
    return {
      lojas: Array,
      loading: 0,
      hero: {
        title: "",
        subtitle: "",
        imgUrl: ""
      }
    }
  },

  //making the query
  apollo: {
    lojas: {
      $loadingKey: 'loading',
      prefetch: true,
      query: getLojaInfo,
      variables () {
        return { slug: this.$route.params.singleLoja }
      },
      //it will wait for query result that and then populate this hero, it will update the hero title, subtitle and image
      result(ApolloQueryResult, key) {
        this.hero.title = ApolloQueryResult.data.lojas[0].name
        this.hero.subtitle = ApolloQueryResult.data.lojas[0].description
        this.hero.imgUrl = ApolloQueryResult.data.lojas[0].logo.url

      //then commit it to Vuex Store
        this.$store.commit("hero/setData", this.hero);

      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Thank you all, I would appreciate contributions to my code.